# How to overlay images in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have two images which I need to overlap.

For ex- I need a solid circle on top of a solid rectangle. So, I can see the entire circle but only the corners of the rectangle. I do not want the circle to be transparent. The original `circle.png` does NOT have a rectangular border. Its border is along the boundaries of the circle only. Thus, ideally, the entire circle should not overlap the rectangle.

This is the code for displaying an image:

```
                BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
                src.BeginInit();
                src.UriSource = new Uri(imgpath, UriKind.Absolute);
                src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                src.EndInit();
                ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush(src);
                ib.Viewbox = new Rect(UVRectangle.X / src.PixelWidth, UVRectangle.Y / src.PixelHeight, UVRectangle.Width / src.PixelWidth, UVRectangle.Height / src.PixelHeight);
                gr.Background = ib; //gr is of type Grid
```

However, if I call this function twice, the second image (circle) completely covers the rectangle and thus, **I end up seeing the background of the canvas** instead of the corners of the rectangle.

I think I need to merge the two images and then paint them. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You override the property Background with your second call. 
If you add two Images to your Grid programmatically it would work. Change:

```
gr.Background = ib;
```

To:

```
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = ib.ImageSource;  
gr.Children.Add(image);
```

Comment: Getting an error:
he best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.Add(System.Windows.UIElement)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush' to 'System.Windows.UIElement'

Comment: Getting another error now:
`An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Controls.Image.Source.get'`

on line
`Image.Source = ib.ImageSource;`

Comment: Sry man. Another fault. I should sleep more! Change the capital I from Image to a small one

Comment: But, `image` is already a variable? And, `image` is not defined otherwise. I don't get you :/

Comment: Look at my edited answer. Of course only the image at the second line

Comment: It works. Thank you so much @Claudio . If its okay, can you leave your email address here?

Comment: Usually I dont share my private email-address in public. Sorry

Comment: its after a while, but there is some problem with this code. While, it has solved the initial problem, there is a new one.

When I place two buttons, one below the other, the one below appears shifted. That does not happen with `gr.Background = ib;` When I change back to the initial code, the buttons are perfectly aligned. What is the problem?

Comment: The Background and a normal Image aren't the same. Maybe you should rethink your GUI. Maybe you should try learn some XAML and the MVVM pattern. It would make things easier. To show dynamic Images you can use Bindings. Have fun.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you can just an ordinary Grid within your XAML. Just place 2 images inside the grid. They will be placed over each other like this:

```
<Grid>
        <Image Source="/ProjectName;component/Folder/Image1.png"
                                Width="24"
                                Height="24" />
        <!-- Image above Image1 -->
        <Image Source="/ProjectName;component/Folder/Image2.png"
                                Width="24"
                                Height="24" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: The images can change dynamically. So, I need to do it in code. Somewhat like what @Claudio suggested

Comment: You can still databind the ImageSource as long as the count of images doesn't change. Otherwise you can of course use Claudio's suggestion.