# Buttons not aligned correctly in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

The customized controls have two images, a background and a foreground image. I use the following code to display the controls. This function is called twice, once for background image displaying and then for the foreground image displaying

```
                BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
                src.BeginInit();
                src.UriSource = new Uri(imgpath, UriKind.Absolute);
                src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                src.EndInit();
                ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush(src);
                ib.Viewbox = new Rect(UVRectangle.X / src.PixelWidth, UVRectangle.Y / src.PixelHeight, UVRectangle.Width / src.PixelWidth, UVRectangle.Height / src.PixelHeight);
                Image image = new Image();
                image.Source = ib.ImageSource;
                gr.Children.Add(image); //gr is of type Grid
```

The buttons are displayed perfectly but I realized that their alignment is incorrect. When I place one button right below another button, the one below appears to be shifted to the right.

This problem of alignment is rectified by changing

```
                Image image = new Image();
                image.Source = ib.ImageSource;
                gr.Children.Add(image);
```

to

```
                gr.Background = ib;
```

But, this makes the foreground image completely cover the background image like I had asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865737/how-to-overlay-images-in-wpf)

What should I do to prevent this alignment problem? Also, what is causing this problem in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try putting the buttons inside stackpanel? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.aspx

Comment: No, but how does that help?

Comment: I am creating a custom UI Editor. I just want the buttons to be displayed the way they are. I may not want all the buttons to be aligned.

Comment: If you use stackpanel, controls inside it will be aligned under each other but just make sure that the size of stackpanel is just right for the controls that you will put inside. Just try if the alignment will be changed.

Comment: If the form was static, it would have been a good idea. But, the buttons may be placed anywhere by the user of the tool. So, should the tool give an option to place a set of buttons inside a stack panel? Or, better, is there a better way to do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865737/how-to-overlay-images-in-wpf

Comment: Do you know why `gr.Children.Add(image)` is causing this problem?

Comment: I have no idea, it can be the cause or it conflicts with some part of the code. Try putting the background image in a canvas instead of grid, check if there's an improvement.